# Actualizar mysql desde Cpanel para instalaciòn de Moodle

Tags: mysql, cpanel, moodle

Cordial saludo,

Tengo un trabajo y tengo un usuario de mi Cpanel, ya logre actualizar PHP pero ahora me solicita que debo actualizar mi versión de base de datos en este caso MySQL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como puedo actualizar desde Cpanel, ya que el usuario fue creado por el Administrador, he estado buscando y no logro encontrar la manera, recordar que todo esta en la nube.

En Cpanel no aparecen algunas, creo que es por el tipo de usuario que me crearon.

Necesito ayuda para salir de la duda si es posible actualizar o definitivamente toca el Administrador del servidor.

Gracias.